# Python.Pandas/:/What is the difference between the first and second codes, so did the following code occur?

Tags: python, pandas

everybody.
Why do files in the first code run and files in the second code fail?

```
import pandas    


SD2=pd.read_csv('C:/Users/Jangsu/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36-32/Sample data1.csv')
DF2=pd.DataFrame(SD2)
SD3=pd.read_csv('C:/Users/Jangsu/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36-32/Sample data2.csv')
DF3=pd.DataFrame(SD3)
SD4=pd.read_csv('C:/Users/Jangsu/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36-32/Sample data3.csv')
DF4=pd.DataFrame(SD4)
SD5=pd.read_csv('C:/Users/Jangsu/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36-32/Sample data4.csv')
DF5=pd.DataFrame(SD5)(

result = pd.concat([DF1,DF2,DF3,DF4],axis=1, ignore_index=False)
print(result)
result.to_csv("savessssssssdata.csv",index=False)
```

When you run the code of the first file, you see that the file running on that code is saved normally.
So let me show you the second code.

```
import pandas as pd
import serial
import time

SD=[]
DF=[]
for i in range(1,4):
    SD1=pd.read_csv('C:/Users/Jangsu/Desktop/Sample 
data'+str(i)+".csv")
    SD.append(SD1)
    DF1=pd.DataFrame(SD1)
    DF.append(DF1)
    DF1.to_csv('C:/Users/Jangsu/Desktop/Samspsle data'+str(i)+".csv",index=False)

resul=pd.concat([DF],axis=1, ignore_index=False)
print(resul)

resul.to_csv("'C:/Users/Jangsu/Desktop/ssssssscccc.csv", 
   index=False)
```

The first code acts as a combination of files.
The second code is the code that will be entered into the DF, which will read each csv file, and then use the code stored in a list format to create and store a single data frame. But the second code has the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/Jangsu/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36-32/csv-testss.py", line 14, in <module>
resul=pd.concat([DF],axis=1, ignore_index=False)
File "C:\Users\Jangsu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\concat.py", line 225, in concat
copy=copy, sort=sort)
File "C:\Users\Jangsu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\concat.py", line 286, in __init__
raise TypeError(msg)
TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type "<class 'list'>"; only pd.Series, pd.DataFrame, and pd.Panel (deprecated) objs are valid
```

What is the difference between the two codes and what is the correct code?

Comment: Your second example uses an undefined variable `DD`, for one thing.

Comment: We've re-upgraded the current code. But there's an error.

Comment: Seems like you need just `pd.concat(DF,....)` instead of `[DF]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DF` is defined as a list, and `[DF]` thus is a list of lists, which cannot be concatenated as the error states. If I understand the logic correctly, here's what you should be doing:

```
filenames = [
    f'C:/Users/Jangsu/Desktop/Sample data{i}.csv'
    for i in range(1, 4)
]

df = pd.concat(
    map(pd.read_csv, filenames), 
    axis=1, 
    ignore_index=False
)
```

Comment: So, how do I combine the code that I wrote above to make it work?

Comment: @임종훈 Do you understand what the code in my answer does? Have you tried running it?

Comment: Ah ha! I tried to see the code you uploaded and it worked normally. Thank you.